# how to define custom mux with golang

Tags: http, go

i have viewed source code of [mux](http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/mux),but i just want something simple ,not using all features.

i wanna get value of *"id"* in the url like /url/{id},setting the value in the req.Form and clean the path like mux.

code like

```
    r:=http.NewServeMux()
    r.HandlerFunc("/",func(w http.ResponseWriter,r *http.Request){
        // Clean path to canonical form and redirect.
        if p := cleanPath(req.URL.Path); p != req.URL.Path {
            url := *req.URL
            url.Path = p
            p = url.String()
            //根据HTTP的协议重定向
            w.Header().Set("Location", p)
            w.WriteHeader(http.StatusMovedPermanently)
            return
        }
                // some code check the url parse id and set to req.form
    })
            //then add some specific url handlers.
```

in go doc ,it says long Pattern will take higher priority than short Pattern.
and i want to run something(parse id , clean path etc) before all handlers.

i don't want to give up the features of defaultmux. should i redefine a brand new route,or use http.NewServeMux()? if i use http.NewServerMux(),how should i do to add something while keeping the features?

Comment: http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/mux is fairly simple, and you don't have to leverage all of the features. Re-inventing the wheel for something simpler will be hard. You could look at https://github.com/drone/routes however.

Comment: exactly,re-inventing wheel is little awkward,but for learning purpose,i just want to have a little try. i just want to know if i do code above and put r as second parameter in http.ServerAndListen works,or redefine a new Handler (give up all features of defaultmux,while i do not want to give up) and put it in http.HandleFunc("/",handler) works.

Answer (score 2):

We have used http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/mux for over a year in our production stack and have been very happy with it.

For some really simple sites I host I use the built in routing something like this:

```
package main

import (
  "flag"
  "fmt"
  "net/http"
  "os"
)

const (
  version = "0.1.0"
)

var (
  port   uint
)

func init() {
  flag.UintVar(&port, "port", 8000, "the port to listen on")
  flag.UintVar(&port, "p", 8000, "the port to listen on")
}

func main() {
  flag.Parse()

  // Retrieve the current working directory.
  path, err := os.Getwd()
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }
  http.HandleFunc("/gallery/view.aspx", handleGallery)
  http.HandleFunc("/gallery/viewLarge.aspx", handleViewLarge)
  http.HandleFunc("/ir.ashx", handleImageResize)
  http.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir(path)))

  panic(http.ListenAndServe(fmt.Sprintf(":%d", port), nil))
}
```

Let me know what you want your routes to be and I could give you a more specific example to what you are looking for.

Comment: just deal with url like `/url/{id}`,but i had used mux instead , feeling good too.